# Launch terminal from keyboard shortcut without focusing on terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

My use case is launching `gnome-terminal` from a keyboard shortcut to run a script on Ubuntu 20.04. I want to keep focus on whatever I was focused on before using the keyboard shortcut. I also want the behaviour when I open a terminal normally to stay the same (the terminal will take focus).

I tried using `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences focus-new-windows 'strict'` to get the behaviour I want, but this also changes the behaviour for opening a terminal normally.

How can I get the behaviour I want when launching the terminal from my keybinding, while preserving the default behaviour for launching the terminal in any other way?

Comment: Just an idea, Perhaps you can install another terminal like Terminator to do your work and use gnome terminal as a script launcher.

Comment: Ah, that totally worked. Thank you so much.